# Cross Origin Error When Using Base64

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, api, base64

I am trying to get an image to appear in my application however the api that I am trying to get the image from has the files as pngs when called so I was trying to use base64 to get the images to work to no avail. 
Here's the code:

```
$("button").on("click",function(){
var num= $("#number").val()
var purl="http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/"+num;
var im="http://pokeapi.co/media/sprites/pokemon/female/12.png"
var unicode=btoa(im);
console.log("pizza")
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
  url:purl,
  success:function(response){
    console.log("hello")
    $("h4").append(response.name)
    console.log(response.name)
    $("h5").text(function(t){
    $.ajax({
      url:unicode,
      success:function(c){
      console.log("blue bessr")
      console.log(c)
      $("#imag").http("<img src="+ c+">")
    },
      error:function(error){
        console.log(error)
      }
    })
  })
  },
  error:function(e){
    console.log(e)
  }
})
})
})
```

Comment: Did you solve your concern now?

Comment: No I haven't. Thanks for checking eeya!

Comment: You might need to check this particular SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present?rq=1 the reason you have the CORS error.